# Letters pop up en Android keyboard

Tags: android, android-edittext

I have these EditText in my app:

```
<EditText
        android:id="@+id/text_url_servidor"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:hint="@string/text_url"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:textSize="7pt" />
```

and

```
  <EditText
                android:id="@+id/login_password"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/login_username"
                android:hint="@string/login_password"
                android:password="true"
                android:singleLine="true"/>
```

When I run the app, the first one shows the letters pop-up, but not the second one. They are in different layouts (xml). Both are inside a `RelativeLayout`. The only difference is that the first one are shown in a `Dialog`. Why second one is not showing letters as pop-up? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it may be because of `android:password="true"` remove it and try

Comment: Yes, it was. How stupid for me! Thank you :) 4 minutes and I accept it